# Make Trusted MSI Setup Project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, trust

I have both VS2008 and VS2010 Setup projects that create .MSI files. On server 2008, I get warnings that the apps are not "trusted". How can I bake-in trust for the apps I build with Visual Studio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they have to be digitally signed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get a software publisher certificate to sign your msi with. You can purchase one from Verisign or GoDaddy.com or others.

Here is a link to one option: http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/code-signing-certificate.aspx